# Unable to login using username

Tags: functions, customization, login

In my website i have signup and sign form.And also I exposes the web services for the signup and sign in form.

**Flow of web as well as mobile application are as follow:**

- For every signup the registered users are receiving an activation link

Below is the code responsible for sending the activation link:

```
// when user login, we will check whether this guy email is verify
function wp_authenticate_user( $userdata ) {
    $isActivated = get_user_meta($userdata->ID, 'is_activated', true);
    if ( !$isActivated ) {
        $userdata = new WP_Error(
            'inkfool_confirmation_error',
            __( '<strong>ERROR:</strong> Your account has to be activated before you can login. You can resend by clicking <a href="/register/?u='.$userdata->ID.'">here</a>', 'inkfool' )
        );
    }
    return $userdata;
}
// when a user register we need to send them an email to verify their account
function my_user_register($user_id) {
    // get user data
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    // create md5 code to verify later
    $code = md5(time());
    // make it into a code to send it to user via email
    $string = array('id'=>$user_id, 'code'=>$code);
    // create the activation code and activation status
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'is_activated', 0);
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'activationcode', $code);
    // create the url
    $url = get_site_url(). '/register/?p=' .base64_encode( serialize($string));
    // basically we will edit here to make this nicer
    $html = 'Please click the following links <br/><br/> <a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';
    // send an email out to user
    wc_mail($user_info->user_email, __('Please activate your account'), $html);
}
// we need this to handle all the getty hacks i made
function my_init(){
    // check whether we get the activation message
    if(isset($_GET['p'])){
        $data = unserialize(base64_decode($_GET['p']));
        $code = get_user_meta($data['id'], 'activationcode', true);
        // check whether the code given is the same as ours
        if($code == $data['code']){
            // update the db on the activation process
            update_user_meta($data['id'], 'is_activated', 1);
            wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Success:</strong> Your account has been activated! ', 'inkfool' )  );
        }else{
            wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Error:</strong> Activation fails, please contact our administrator. ', 'inkfool' )  );
        }
    }
    if(isset($_GET['q'])){
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Error:</strong> Your account has to be activated before you can login. Please check your email.', 'inkfool' ) );
    }
    if(isset($_GET['u'])){
        my_user_register($_GET['u']);
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Succes:</strong> Your activation email has been resend. Please check your email.', 'inkfool' ) );
    }
}
// hooks handler
add_action( 'init', 'my_init' );
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'wc_registration_redirect');
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'wp_authenticate_user',10,2);
add_action('user_register', 'my_user_register',10,2);
```

**Issue am facing is :**

- Everything is working fine when it comes to the signup from mobile, the registered user unable to login using username from website but they can login using email.However, users are able to login successfully through mobile app via username as well as email.

Comment: You should avoid using `serialise` and `unserialize` for security reasons, there are a number of attacks possible, especially where user input is involved

Comment: @ Tom What should i used instead of serialise and unserialize

Comment: XML, or `json_encode` and `json_decode`, though I don't see where the `$_GET['p']` parameter is generated so you may have no control over that